# Using `remind` to get next weeks schedule

Tags: linux, bash, reminders

I have just started using the remind tool on GNU/Linux: [remind man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/remind).
I have the following bash functions using remind to get todays, tomorrows and this weeks reminders

```
today() {
  remind $SCHEDULE
}
tomorrow() {
  tomorrow=`date --date=tomorrow +"%d %b %Y"`
  remind $SCHEDULE $tomorrow
}
thisweek() {
  remind -mc+ $SCHEDULE
}
```

Here $SCHEDULE is the path to my reminder file i use for all appointments, anniversaries etc. `today` and `tomorrow` simply uses `remind` to list the reminders for a single day in list form. In `thisweek`, `remind -mc` generates a table for the present week with all reminders for the involved dates. I would like to have a `nextweek` function that generates the table for the next week ie. the days Monday through Sunday where Monday is the first Monday after todays date. I cant figure out if this is doable using `remind`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any options for remind to do it directly, so awk to the rescue: output 2 week's worth, and remove the first week with awk.

```
remind -mc+2 "$SCHEDULE" | awk '/^\+/ {n++} n!=2'
```